# Efficient way of extracting data, from json file. And transforming it into dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

Imagine i have a list containing multiple dictionaries

Sample dict

```
{'city': None, 'bot-origin': None, 'campaign-source': 'attendance bot', 'lastState': 'productAvailabilityCpfValidationTrue', 'main-installation-date': None, 'userid': '00377a70-fc79-424e-80c3-1f0324094378@tunnel.msging.net', 'full-name': None, 'alternative-installation-date': None, 'chosen-product': 'Internet', 'bank': None, 'postalcode': '82100690', 'due-date': None, 'cpf': '07670115971', 'origin-link': '', 'payment': None, 'state': None, 'api-orders-hash-id': None, 'email': None, 'api-orders-error': None, 'plan-name': None, 'userphone': '41 9893-6613', 'plan-offer': None, 'completed-address': None, 'type-of-person': 'CPF', 'onboarding-simplified': None, 'type-of-product': 'Residencial', 'main-installation-period-day': None, 'plan-value': None, 'alternative-installation-period-day': None, 'data-change': 'false'}
```

The list contains around 9000000, events such as the one displayed.

What i want to do is basically, break them apart into a kinda of dataframe format such as `pd.DataFrame()` (i dont insist on it), but unfortunately. I tried commands such as `pd.json_normalize()`, `read_json`, `from_records` and so on and they seen to be well consuming all my memory.
My approach is to do some sort of chunksize, where i split the list/series into chunks, load them into variables put them into df format save them, and then clean  out the memory, and after that concatenate everything. So you know my pc doesnt crash while trying to load everything at once.

Here is my attempt

```
def forma_extras(extras):
   # Extras = serialized json, in series object format
   for i in range(0,extras.size[0],100):
        #Having a little trouble here
```

Comment: What happens when you load the json into memory with `json.loads()`? Will the computer crash?

Comment: `pd.read_json` has a `chunksize` parameter exactly for this purpose.

Comment: @AndrejKesely no actually the converting into python objects is okey dokey

Comment: Then as @fsimonjetz mentioned, try to use `chunksize=` parameter in `pd.read_json` (if the json is line delimited). If not split the list with dictionaries (that you load with `json.loads()` into chunks, create a dataframe from this chunk and save it to disk (as CSV?).

Comment: I see i will try chunksize, and if that doesnt work. I shall give you the answer later

Comment: Well couldnt use chunk size because well my json was not newline splited, so i did the following approach check answer

Answer (score 0):

My solutions was something like this
At least my computer doesnt crash when i run this
Is this the most efficient i am not sure, maybe saving it and just taking out of memory would be better, will be doing following steps

```
def forma_extras(extras):
    chunk = 100000
    l_extra = []
    for i in range(0,len(extras),chunk):
        chunks = i + chunk
        l_extra.append(pd.DataFrame.from_records(extras[i:chunks]))
```